# Python - How to run module from IDLE vs. command prompt

Tags: python, module, pip

I installed the moneywagon module using pip, for both python 2.7 and 3.4, and from the command prompt I can run commands, eg

```
moneywagon service-table
```

and it gives the correct output.
But from IDLE python3.4, I tried

```
>>>>import moneywagon
```

or simply

```
>>>>moneywagon service-table
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also tried

```
>>> from moneywagon import service-table
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

The commands are different for the command prompt and for the IDLE interface, for some reason.

In the documentation for moneywagon (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/moneywagon), there is a section entitled

"# Python Interface"

which gives commands that work in IDLE.